# Spring Batch Integration JobLaunchRequest from Controller

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-integration

I have a controller from which I would like to run a Spring Batch job. The FilePoller acts as a poller that runs on a schedule but we'd like to run it manually, too. The FilePoller is working on the cron schedule and the JobLaunchRequest works in this fashion. But when we use JobLaunchRequest called from the controller, nothing happens -- the Spring Batch job is not launched. Here is the controller:

```
@Controller
public class PollerController {

@Autowired
FilePoller FilePoller;

@Autowired
private ApplicationContext appContext;

@RequestMapping(value = "ui/manualPoll.action", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void manualPollRequest() {

    Message<File> message = filePoller.fileMessageSource().receive();

    filePoller.setFileParameterName(message.getPayload().getName());        
    filePoller.setJob((Job)appContext.getBean("myJob"));

    filePoller.toRequest(message);
}
```

The message payload has the file name and I get the Spring Batch job to run from the application context. I have debugged and stepped through code and ensured that the file name from the message payload is not null and that the Spring Batch job is also not null. Inside the FilePoller class I have this:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:my.properties") 
@EnableIntegration
@IntegrationComponentScan
public class FilePoller {

private Job job;

private String fileParameterName;

@Autowired
MyProperty myProperty;

public void setFileParameterName(String fileParameterName) {
    this.fileParameterName = fileParameterName;
}

public void setJob(Job job) {
    this.job = job;
}

@Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter(value = "inboundFileChannel", poller = @Poller(cron="${my/POLLER}"))
public MessageSource<File> fileMessageSource() {
    FileReadingMessageSource source = initialSetUp();
    source.setDirectory(new File(myProperty.getProperty(MyConstants.WORKING_DIR)))
    return source;
}

private FileReadingMessageSource initialSetUp() {
    FileReadingMessageSource source = new FileReadingMessageSource();
    CompositeFileListFilter<File> compositeFileListFilter = new CompositeFileListFilter<File>(); 
    SimplePatternFileListFilter simplePatternFileListFilter = new SimplePatternFileListFilter("*.done");
    AcceptOnceFileListFilter<File> acceptOnceFileListFilter = new AcceptOnceFileListFilter<File>();

    compositeFileListFilter.addFilter(simplePatternFileListFilter);
    compositeFileListFilter.addFilter(acceptOnceFileListFilter);

    source.setFilter(compositeFileListFilter);
    return source;
}

@Transformer
public JobLaunchRequest toRequest(Message<File> message) {
    JobParametersBuilder jobParametersBuilder = new JobParametersBuilder();
    jobParametersBuilder.addString(fileParameterName, message.getPayload().getAbsolutePath());
    return new JobLaunchRequest(job, jobParametersBuilder.toJobParameters());
}
```

The JobLaunchRequest doesn't seem to do anything. I never get into my first step, shown here in the XML config:

```
<int:annotation-config />           
<int:channel id="inboundFileChannel" />
<int:channel id="outboundJobRequestChannel" />
<int:channel id="jobLaunchReplyChannel" />  

<int:transformer input-channel="inboundFileChannel"
    output-channel="outboundJobRequestChannel">
    <bean
        class="org.my.poller.FilePoller">
        <property name="job" ref="myJob" />
        <property name="fileParameterName" value="input.file.name" />
    </bean>
</int:transformer>

<batch-int:job-launching-gateway request-channel="outboundJobRequestChannel" reply-channel="jobLaunchReplyChannel" />
<int:logging-channel-adapter channel="jobLaunchReplyChannel" />



<job id="myJob" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
        <step id="Step1" next="Step2">
            <tasklet ref="checkifFileinLogTbl"/>
```

**UPDATE**
Thanks, Gary. It works now. If anyone else is interested:

```
@Autowired
MessageChannel outboundJobRequestChannel;

@Autowired
MessagingTemplate template;

@RequestMapping(value = "ui/manualPoll.action", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void manualPollRequest() {

Message<File> message = filePoller.fileMessageSource().receive();

    //if message !=null, there is a file present on inboundFileChannel
    if(message !=null){
        filePoller.setFileParameterName("input.file.name");
        filePoller.setJob((Job) appContext.getBean("myJob"));

        template.convertAndSend(outboundJobRequestChannel, filePoller.toRequest(message));
    }
```

And in the XML I added:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
filePoller.toRequest(message);
```

Just builds the request object.

You need to send it to the `outboundJobRequestChannel`.

Use a `MessagingTemplate` (`convertSendAndReceive()`) or a [`MessagingGateway`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#gateway) to do that.